# Multiple Public Keys PKI Package [R]

Tags: r, key, public, bitcoin, pki

I am educating myself on cryptocurrencies and a theme within that community is to use separate "addresses" for each transaction.  As I interpret an address as the hash of the public key for the individual, it leads me to believe that you can generate multiple public keys for a private key.  I am completely novice on this subject and am using the R PKI package as a jumping off point for this self tutorial.

This line of thinking is counter to the discussion at [PKI multiple public keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100192/pki-multiple-public-keys) so I might be well of the mark but if not is there a way to generate an additional public key with the PKI package?

I have a code block below that covers some of my thinking.  Now having said all this.  I am trying to understand some 9 pages of discussion as to what that implies and I don't think I am up for finite groups discussion nor the compromise of the Private Key if multiple public keys are released.  SO if you can correct me via programming or additional reference material I would appreciate.  Ultimately, its and exercise to improve my R skills first and foremost.

```
require(PKI)

# generate 2048-bit RSA key
key <- PKI.genRSAkey(bits = 2048L)

# extract private and public parts as PEM
priv.pem <- PKI.save.key(key)
pub.pem <- PKI.save.key(key, private=FALSE)
# load back the public key separately
pub.k <- PKI.load.key(pub.pem)

# encrypt with the public key
x <- PKI.encrypt(charToRaw("Hello, world!"), pub.k)
# decrypt with private key
rawToChar(PKI.decrypt(x, key))

# So straight from the Package examples I have the public and private keys.

# Additionally, with the same I can sign a message
x <- charToRaw("My message to sign")
sig <- PKI.sign(x, key)
PKI.verify(x, sig, key)

# Now a slight change from the exapmles I will verify that the public key can verify
PKI.verify(x, sig, pub.k)

# Now I would like to generate another public key based on the same private key
# my nieve attempt is 

#PKI.mkRSApubkey(modulus, exponent=65537L, format = c("DER", "PEM", "key"))
pub.k

pub.k2<-PKI.mkRSApubkey(123, exponent=65537L, format =  "key")
pub.k2

PKI.verify(x, sig, pub.k2)

PKI.verify(x, sig, pub.k)

priv.pem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in saying that bitcoin addresses should not be reused.

A bitcoin private key only has one public key, but it can be in different formats, compressed or uncompressed. For example, the private key `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`

has a corresponding uncompressed public key of `04a34b99f22c790c4e36b2b3c2c35a36db06226e41c692fc82b8b56ac1c540c5bd5b8dec5235a0fa8722476c7709c02559e3aa73aa03918ba2d492eea75abea235`

and a compressed public key of `03a34b99f22c790c4e36b2b3c2c35a36db06226e41c692fc82b8b56ac1c540c5bd`

Hashing them will result in the address `1HZwkjkeaoZfTSaJxDw6aKkxp45agDiEzN` and `1F3sAm6ZtwLAUnj7d38pGFxtP3RVEvtsbV` respectively.

You should only use compressed publics keys as uncompressed public keys bloat the blockchain. 
That being said, since you should only use one of those address for a private key, that means you should also use a different private key for every transaction.
Now this creates a host of other problems, like key management becomes a lot more troublesome since you have to generate a new private key every time you want to do a transaction. You should look into hierarchical deterministic wallets as that is an establish standard that is meant to deal with some of these issues.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  Trying to program this all up uncovers a lot of hand waving issues.  I was actually thinking that a key server would provide the public key (Still just going off the 9 page paper and jumping right to how would I program it) I think my choice of RSA key vice Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm explains the nice short version of a public key and likely signature you provided examples of.  Again thanks.